# How to return response from .then block?

Tags: node.js

I have a method that makes an HTTP call using Axios Library,
The HTTP is working fine but, I am unable to return data from the .then block,

**Following is my method -**

```
module.exports.postAPI = async (url, headers, data) => {

    console.log("URL => ", url);
    console.log("Payload => ", headers);
    console.log("Data => ", data);

    await axios({ method: 'POST', url: url, headers: headers, data: data })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("POST API Call Successful \n");  
        console.log("POST Response => \n", response.data); 
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("POST API Call Unsuccessful \n", error,"\n");
        return error;
    });
}
```

**Call to postAPI -**

```
let test = async () => {

    let url = 'someURL';

    let headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };

    let data = {
            "someKey": "someValue"
    };

    let response = await commonUtil.postAPI(url, headers, data);
        console.log("UTIL Response => \n", response);
}
```

`POST API Call Successful and POST Response => and response.data`is getting printed,
But data is not getting returned to the calling function.

Comment: I don't see the `commonUtil` declaration in your code

Comment: `let response =await axios({ method: 'POST', url: url, headers: headers, data: data }) 
return response.data`

Comment: you mix async/await with a promise. You have choose one of the them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports.postAPI = async (url, headers, data) => {
  try {
     const { data } = await axios({ method: 'POST', url: url, headers: headers, data: data });
     return data;
} catch(error){
    return error;
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Either use Async/await or promises

Async/await

```
    module.exports.postAPI = async (url, headers, data) => {

    console.log("URL => ", url);
    console.log("Payload => ", headers);
    console.log("Data => ", data);
    try{

         let response=await axios.post(url,data, {headers: headers} )
         console.log("POST API Call Successful \n");  
         console.log("POST Response => \n", response.data); 
         return response.data;
    }
    catch(err){
         console.log("POST API Call Unsuccessful \n", err,"\n");
         return err
    }
}
```

Promises

```
module.exports.postAPI = (url, headers, data) => {

    console.log("URL => ", url);
    console.log("Payload => ", headers);
    console.log("Data => ", data);

    axios.post(url,data, {headers: headers} )
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("POST API Call Successful \n");  
        console.log("POST Response => \n", response.data); 
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
         console.log("POST API Call Unsuccessful \n", error,"\n");
         return error;
    });
}
```

Comment: I removed async from function declaration and await as well, code print POST Response => and then disappears.